# When is the game saved, and how?

Tags: diablo-iii

I just disconnected and my quest seems to have been reset to a few minutes before where I currently was. However, it seems like I kept everything in my inventory that I found in meantime.

When exactly is the game automatically saved? And what kind of stuff usually goes lost when something happens without the game having saved?

Also, is there some way to save manually? Is the game saved when I log out?

Comment: Did you disconnect from the singleplayer? >that's the punchline

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In terms of your inventory and such, there is no such thing as the game "saving", updates are instantly applied to the server, so it isn't possible to lose anything.  In terms of quests, there are frequent "checkpoints" throughout the game (usually about every 5-10 minutes).  Anytime you stop playing, you will resume the quest from your last checkpoint the next time you start again.  There is no way to force a quest save other than reaching one of these points.