# How can I save the game?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When is the game saved, and how?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66238/when-is-the-game-saved-and-how)

I would like to play D3 in my lunch time, but I'm worried about one thing.

Is there a way to save my progress in the game, besides the check-points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check-points are for quests only. As per your inventory is concerned, it's auto-updated to the server.

Answer (score 2):

Diablo 3 is all saved as you go. You can leave and resume where you left off at any time.